# Ругается на QT_DEPRECATED_SINCE

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qtcreator, mingw

Имеется проект. Отлично компилируется через MSVC, но мне надо перекомпилировать под MinGW. Вылазит очень много таких ошибок. Посмотрел в интернете, что это значит и там написано, мол я использую устаревшие функции, но их у меня в проекте нет. Что я не так делаю. Проект выложу по требованию.

пример ошибки

> C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtCore\qchar.h:422: ошибка: missing binary operator before token "("
>    #if QT_DEPRECATED_SINCE(5, 0)
>                           ^

Comment: а под студией используется также версия qt5.7

Comment: Я пишу в том же Qt Creator+MSVC. Да, версии одинаковые

Comment: я знаю две причины - либо у Вас путях прописаны пути к старым версиям Qt (такое бывает), либо в проекте используется файл, имя которого совпадает с "системным". Происходит путаница и компилятор выдает бред. Пример - https://forum.qt.io/topic/27925/solved-qt_deprecated_since-gives-error-missing-binary-operator-before-token-in-qnamespace-h/3

Comment: Вроде проверял, пути в норме. Файлы? Хм. Ну вроде тоже не совпадают(у меня файлы: ai, field, fieldclass, indexesandstatus, kicks, process, ship, startdialog, window, aboutdialog исходники и такие же заголовочные) Что же из этого может быть конфликтным. Перепроверю сейчас

Comment: Нет, нету повторяющихся файлов

Comment: нет, я не о повторяющихся файлах в пределах проекта. А вот к примеру, вполне может быть, что gcc использует файл с именем process.h или field.h. И если это так - это и будет корень проблем.

Comment: Да, нашел файл process.h в инклюдах mingw, поменял в проекте свой файл на другое название, но ошибки так и остались

Comment: Проблема всё ещё актуальна

Comment: Выкладывайте уже проект. Лучше конечно привести его к виду [mcve].

Comment: Но ведь в ошибке, приведённой в вопросе, `deprecated` это не заявление компилятора, а строка исходного кода. Компилятор не опознал `QT_DEPRECATED_SINCE(5, 0)` как допустимую конструкцию и требует какой-нибудь оператор (типа сложения/вычитания) перед скобкой. По-моему, пока корни проблемы ищутся не там.

Comment: я стыкался с подобной проблемой. Как оказалось, один "горе-специалист" обявил макрос с именем `debug`, в результате любой вызов `qDebug()` при компиляции давал разухабистые ошибки.
Но в данном случае думаю, что произошла путаница заголовочных файлов.